# Dynamic query with mongodb in BIRT

Tags: mongodb, report, birt

I have to make a  birt report with 3 parameters which should be used in query. The parameters are two dates and a string.

I tried to do it in beforeOpen dataset as indicated for sql queries, but it has not worked.

I write in beforeOpen expression dataset:

```
this.queryText = '{
"findQueryExpr": { "ref":  "'+params["ref"].value+'",  "sts": { $gt: "'+params["startDate"].value+'" , $lte: "'+params["endDate"].value+'"} } , 
"operationType" : "FIND" , 
"collectionName" : "events", 
"queryReadPreference" : "secondary" , 
"selectedFields" : [ "ref" , "sts" , "rts" , "c.value" , "c.type" , "c.quality" , "r.value" , "r.type" , "r.quality"] 
}';
```

And the query is throwing on the total number of documents in the collection regardless of the parameters.

It is possible to make mongo query in Birt with parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Double click on your Data-set, select "Property Binding" and enter your function into the query text.

You should also set your query string to a global persistent variabel and print it on your report for debugging, making sure your final statement is valid. The Dates could be in a different format in your report and the database and lead to not restricting your result set:

```
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("testglobal", queryString);// in the script of your data source.
reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable('testglobal');//in a dynamic text fild.
```